# Init OpenGL on android platform from native code

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I want to initialize OpenGL ES on Android platform from native code.

I just want to draw on some part of activity, for example, on panel or smth like this.
In Windows platform I use HWND handler to specify "part" of form to draw on...

In ***NDK/samples/native-activity*** I found some example. In this example ***ANativeWindow*** is used (like HWND in Windows (as far as I understood) ).

But how to pass ANativeWindow pointer to native code?

Comment: 9 questions, no answer accepted... you won't get any answer here unless you give credits to people who take time to answer your questions.